# How can I inspect the java WAR file generated by Codenvy?

Tags: java, ide

I am generating and deploying a WAR file to GAE, but I'm not sure how it's constructing the WAR.  Is there any way to view the compiled WAR in Codenvy?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the IDE, the Output tab will list a snapshot link that allows you to download the WAR file created as well as the other build artifacts.

It will look something like: http://builder.codenvycorp.com/repository/com/codenvy/testapp/1.0-SNAPSHOT

and list out all of your recent build artifacts

Comment: Can't find the output TAB :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the IDE, but in the Builder tab, in te most upper left there is a link with label "Artifact" thats points to your generated war.
You must have the runner in "play" mode, otherwise the war cant be downlodeable.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.